What's the difference between collection2 of Raw Scenes and TOA
I'm a beginner of GEE, I can't distinguish the difference of Landsat collection2 of Raw Scenes and TOA, such as 'USGS Landsat 7 Collection 2 Tier 1 Raw Scenes' and 'USGS Landsat 7 Collection 2 Tier 1 TOA Reflectance', and whether the 'LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR' is 'USGS Landsat 7 Collection 2 Tier 1 Raw Scenes' or not?
If I want to calculate the NDVI, which collection should I choose?

Your best bet for calculating indices like NDVI is to use "surface reflectance" data, already corrected for atmospheric distortion. TOA is "top of atmosphere" and "raw scenes" are just that - uncorrected.
Remember that you can get the full metadata from the source (USGS EROS). For example, USGS EROS Archive - Landsat Archives - Landsat Collection 2 U.S Analysis Ready Data (ARD) Product. I like the ARD datasets because they contain additional quality information. But they don't appear to be available through GEE.
Look at the GEE data catalog - you'll see what you want there, too. Here are a couple of examples:
USGS Landsat 8 Level 2, Collection 2, Tier 1
USGS Landsat 9 Level 2, Collection 2, Tier 1
In short, don't use "raw scenes" and don't use "TOA Reflectance" if you want an accurate index. It may be good enough for your application, but it's not worth it when the right data sets are there for the taking.
And I prefer Landsat 8 or 9 to Landsat 7. Unless you know you want Landsat 7, there are longstanding instrument issues on that platform.
